# Set loading limits by file extension in nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I am using the following command to limit file upload in nginx;

```
client_max_body_size 100m;
```

But I want to do it based on file extensions. For example, 5 mb for png, 10 mb for jpg. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code. but i did not try;

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif) 
{ 
client_max_body_size 1m; 
...proxy_pass or whatever 
} 

location ~* ^.+\.(zip|rar) 
{ 
client_max_body_size 10m;
...proxy_pass or whatever
}
```